# Renombrar imagen en eclipse (Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Estoy realizando una app en `Android` y necesito que se renombre una imagen seleccionada de la galería con un nombre concreto y no encuentro nada que me pueda resultar útil.

Mi idea era coger el nombre de la ImageView, no sé si lo debo coger de ahí o de otro lado, y una vez recogido el nombre en una variable, cambiarla por`nombre.setText(codigo + "_inicio");`

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Puedes compartir tu código?

Comment: He realizado tantos cambios que borré lo que tenía para renombrar archivos

Comment: Pues sin una base sobre la que comentar, difícil.

Comment: Lo entiendo, pero estoy completamente perdida con este proyecto. Y no poder hacer pruebas me lo complica todavía más..